# Android connectycube not working when using proguard

Tags: connectycube

When using proguard connectycube user login is not working for video chat connectycube sdk version 1.8.1.
what are the rules for proguard.

Comment: which code (https://github.com/ConnectyCube/android-messenger-app or other) do you use for video chat? please provide more information about errors you have got during build or runtime

Answer (score 1):

try use snippet below to resolve issues related with connectycube-android-sdk, it should help you:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses  

-keep class com.connectycube.auth.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.auth.model.** { *; }

-keep class com.connectycube.core.parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.core.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.core.server.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.core.rest.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.core.error.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.core.Query { *; }

-keep class com.connectycube.users.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.users.model.** { *; }

-keep class com.connectycube.chat.parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.chat.model.** { *; }

-keep class com.connectycube.pushnotifications.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.pushnotifications.model.** { *; }

-keep class com.connectycube.storage.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.connectycube.storage.model.** { *; }

-keep class org.jivesoftware.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.jivesoftware.smackx.**

-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
```